# In PySpark, using regexp_replace, how to replace a group with value from another column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with two columns: `filename` and `year`. I want to replace the year value in `filename` with value from `year` column

Third column in the below table demonstrates the requirement:

```
+----------------------------+------+----------------------------+
| filename                   | year | reqd_filename              |
+----------------------------+------+----------------------------+
| blah_2020_v1_blah_blah.csv | 1975 | blah_1975_v1_blah_blah.csv |
+----------------------------+------+----------------------------+
| blah_2019_v1_blah_blah.csv | 1984 | blah_1984_v1_blah_blah.csv |
+----------------------------+------+----------------------------+
```

Code currently looks like below:

```
df = df.withColumn('filename', F.regexp_replace(F.col('filename',), '(blah_)(.*)(_v1.*)', <Nothing I put here works>))
```

In short, I want to replace the second group with `year` column from df

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [expr](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr).
I'm using `([0-9]{4})` as the regex pattern for detecting a year in `filename`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn("reqd_filename",expr("regexp_replace(filename, \
        '([0-9]{4})', year)")).show()

+--------------------------+----+--------------------------+                    
|filename                  |year|reqd_filename             |
+--------------------------+----+--------------------------+
|blah_2020_v1_blah_blah.csv|1975|blah_1975_v1_blah_blah.csv|
|blah_2019_v1_blah_blah.csv|1984|blah_1984_v1_blah_blah.csv|
+--------------------------+----+--------------------------+
```

Comment: This is totally the correct answer. What a shame that `F.regexp_replace(...)` doesn't allow to use a Column as a third parameter just like the `F.expr("regexp_replace(...)")` version does. It just makes everything dirtier.

Comment: Can you also obtain the second or third group this way?